# Need application to run without root access

Tags: linux, debian, raid, sudo

i try to build my local services system inhouse, and to thant i need to learn how i can give access to a single user with out type a root access when i do it, or i need to know how i can call the application include the root access.

my problem is i need to handle something about my software raid on Debian 8 and when i try to changes something on it with the command `madam` its every time say `promotion deiend` or i need to run it as `sudo`

So now to my system i want to add a custom user like `system-config` to handle what i want and to that i need to tell witch applications this user have access to like `mdadm` and what i else want to.

can sombardy here help me? i have trying in my sudoer's file but i think i'm totally wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Look...

You need a minimal command at root or sudo, to add sudo group on your user.

But, if root access is impossible, try to install at your user home the same program, and run locally.

If you need the program doesn't shutdown after you terminal close, use & at end of command.

You can download a compatible .sh or .zip directly on ventor site... I had this operation with mysql and it worked.

Hope help you.